# Python GUI Alarm Clock using Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, alarm

I wrote a simple program for implementing an Alarm Clock in Python GUI using Tkinter module. By my knowledge, the logic is somewhat right but it is not working for me. Here are some code snippets
I use playsound module for playing an alarm sound, and I made a function so that when the time comes it just chimes.

```
def alarmClock(setHour,setMin):
    if(setHour==datetime.datetime.now().hour and setMin==datetime.datetime.now().minute):
        while(msvcrt.kbhit()):
            playsound.playsound("#path of the alarm sound")
            break

        Label(clock,text="Wake up").place(x=300,y=500)
        return True
```

And I implemented this function in

```
Button(command=lambda(alarmClock(tkvar1.get(),tkvar2.get())))
```

where `tkvar1` and `tkvar2` are `StringVar()` objects which contain the minute and hours the user selects from the dropdown OptionMenu.
One other thing I did is that I wanted to keep it simple, so I only added upto 12 hrs for the 12hr format and then when the user enters whether the alarm is set for AM or PM, the hours will change accordingly(hour + 12 if it is PM so that it fits the 24 hr format which datetime() module supports).
I have a feeling that I messed up at either the 12 hr to 24 hr format conversion, or the OptionMenu option. Sorry for the bad English. Kindly help me find the solution

Comment: That isn't how you use `lambda`. Change that to `Button(command=lambda: alarmClock(tkvar1.get(),tkvar2.get()))`

Comment: Sorry. I did that in my code earlier. When I typed it came out wrong. In my code it is there as `Button(command=lambda: alarmClock(tkvar1.get(),tkvar2.get()))` . Doesn't work as I expected

Comment: Your code will only evaluate whether the alarm time matches the current time once after you press the button. You need to check this periodically. I'd suggest using the tkinter `.after` method to schedule a function to run every 60 seconds after the button has been pressed. Also your "Wake Up"  label will only be shown after the user has pressed a key.

Comment: You are right. I must have added while(True): or something and make it run like that. Thanks